# How to print a gsp from controller using a printer?

Tags: templates, grails, controller

I need to pass some values to a template and then print the template. How can I achieve that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: By print I mean sending the template to a printer.

Comment: If you want people to help, you should describe what you have tried. Try to post some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, you want to automatically start printing of rendered gsp page.
You shouldn't try to do this from the controller, the controller is used for passing parameters to .gsp page which is rendered as HTML.

You can automatically start printer by putting this javascript in your gsp file:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    window.print();
});

</script>
```